# acts_as_list "NoMethodError (undefined method `position_was' for xxx)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place, acts-as-list

I'm trying to update the `theme_name` using `Best In Place`. At the moment however, it throws an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `position_was' for #<Fruit:0x000000037e80a8>):
  app/controllers/fruits_controller.rb:18:in `update'
```

I have a resource called `fruit` and one called `theme`. `fruit` belongs to `theme` and `theme` has many `fruit`. Themes are set through `fruit` using getter and setter methods:

```
#fruit.rb
  def theme_name
    theme.try(:name)
  end

  def theme_name= name
    self.theme = Theme.find_or_create_by(name: name) if name.present?
    self.theme.conversation_id = self.conversation_id
  end
```

I also mention now that both `theme`s and `fruit` belong to `conversation`. The `fruit` resource `acts_as_list`.

This is the update action in `fruits_controller.rb`, it only responds to JSON

```
  def update
    @fruit = Fruit.find(params[:id])
    @fruit.update_attributes(fruit_params)

    respond_with_bip(@fruit)
  end
```

Using the `best_in_place` update I get the error. Here is the full output from the dev console:

```
Started PUT "/fruits/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-03 20:32:57 +0000
Processing by FruitsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"fruit"=>{"theme_name"=>"Candy"}, "authenticity_token"=>"UdsIgUglpPjkD5PS64PCxV9JyJFLlNxrO3tg8E9oe8o=", "id"=>"12"}
  Fruit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "fruits".* FROM "fruits" WHERE "fruits"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "12"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Theme Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "themes".* FROM "themes" WHERE "themes"."name" = 'Candy' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "themes" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 03 Dec 2013 20:32:57 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Candy"], ["updated_at", Tue, 03 Dec 2013 20:32:57 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "fruits" SET "theme_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "fruits"."id" = 12  [["theme_id", 1], ["updated_at", Tue, 03 Dec 2013 20:32:57 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `position_was' for #<Fruit:0x000000037e80a8>):
  app/controllers/fruits_controller.rb:18:in `update'
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated. If I have failed to explain myself anywhere please let me know so I can amend it!

Edit:

[Here's](https://github.com/Jragon/OTIS) a link to the github page for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there's no column 'Position'. I was using rank instead. This is what the `act_as_list` call should have looked like:

```
acts_as_list column: :rank, scope: :conversation
```